# Take an iPhone photo from python or command line

Tags: python, ios

I would like to connect to an iPhone from my laptop and get the iPhone to take a photo, preferably using python but using a command line would also work. I know how to do this on android phones using adb and python-adb. I was wondering if there was something equivalent for iOS.

Comment: easiest way is to SSH over USB and do it that way, however I cannot remember if you need root access to the device to actually transfer meaningful data. If you do you, the device will have to be jailbroken to gain root access.

Comment: I just need to send to phone a take photo command, the photo can be stored on the phone itself so I don't transfer any data.

Comment: how to you expect to send a command (if there even is a take photo command) to the device if information can't be sent to it? Remember that iOS devices are computers with a jailed operating system